# htaccess Rerwite rules colliding

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have to rewrite rules that collide with each other. Actually, it's the second rule that causes the first not to work, even when I switch positions.

artistmusic.php

```
From: http://www.example.com/artistmusic?slug=Ben
To: http://www.example.com/Ben/music
```

artistvideos.php

```
From: http://www.example.com/artistvideos?slug=Ben
To: http://www.example.com/Ben/videos
```

Rewrite rule for the above urls.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /artist$2?address=$1 [L]
```

This works like it should, until I add the rewrite rule for the set of URls below.

allsongs.php

```
From: http://www.example.com/allsongs?standard=popular&request=monthly
To: http://www.example.com/songs/popular/monthly
```

allartists.php

```
From: http://www.example.com/allartists?standard=popular&request=monthly
To: http://www.example.com/artists/popular/monthly
```

Rewrite rule for the second set above.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /all$1?standard=$2&request=$3
```

The rule above works but kills the first one.
What is the cause of this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples/attempts, please have your htaccess rules file in following manner. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^songs/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ allsongs.php?standard=$1&request=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^artists/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ allartists.php?standard=$1&request=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(music|videos)/?$ artist$2.php?slug=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

---

---

***Generic solution:*** In case you don't want to hard code values in your new rules then try following. Make sure use either above OR following only 1 at a time.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ all$1.php?standard=$2&request=$3 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ artist$2.php?slug=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: @Busker McGreen Brian, could you please do let me know if these Rules have worked for you?